# Laravel how can i set session flash data for two requests and how to access it in the view file

Tags: laravel

I have this code in my controller

```
$request->session()->keep(['username', 'test_user']);
```

I want to retrieve data from session in view

Comment: you need to put more information into your question about when you want to use this variable

Comment: I have a login page , if the user enter invalid data, it going to the login page to display the error  after two requests, the problem is that if i set flash data , i lose the session data, the reason i think is that the login page showing only after 2 requests,

Comment: https://readouble.com/laravel/6.x/en/session.html
Look at

Comment: in what controller and where are you calling this line of code? why are there 2 redirects and not 1 after login failure? when are you originally setting these 2 flash vars?

Comment: were you able to display the session variables on the blade file after the first request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

In your controller:

```
session()->flash('username','my name is abc');
```

In your view file:

```
@if(Session::has('username')) 
    {{ session('username') }} 
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [session helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session#retrieving-data) to retrieve data in your view:

```
<div>
  User name: {{session('username')}}
</div>
```

Comment: you can use session helper to set values as well: `session(['username' => 'test_name']);`